Can I use the Allocation instruments while running an XCUITest?
Can I use the Allocations instrument while running an XCUITest?
I have a long running XCUITest where memory usage keeps growing over time. It's not immediately clear what is causing this. I spent a good amount of time looking at the Memory Graph but this hasn't been useful, particularly because it's not easy to see which objects use the most memory.
Can I use the Allocations instrument on the XCUItest ?

No, directly running an Allocations instrument alongside an XCUITest isn't supported. There are limitations with Xcode that prevent profiling the XCUITest itself while it's executing the tests.
